# XSD for Element Or OtherElement Or Text

Tags: xsd, complextype

I need an XSD for the following construct:

```
Expression := <FunctionCall> | <OperatorConstruct> | <Variable> | Constant_Text
```

In other words, the Expression type consist of a choice between 3 other types and a text.
I know there is a `xs:Choice` element, but I can't figure out how to write the 'Or Text' part. Simply using mixed=true on the Expression element allows to enter text AND other elements, but I would like to limit to only one from those four.
So the question is, what xsd can I define that allows one of three elements or a text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your structure validated by an XML Schema, you'll have to make all four choices into elements. [MathML](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/) expressions work that way, with elements for every term.

Or you could go with `mixed` and validate the structure outside of XSD (with XSLT or Schematron or your own parsing code).